# Combine in the same assembly Entity Data Model genereted by different version of Entity Framework. Is it possible?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working in a project which was originally created  in Visual Studio 2010, .Net framework 4.0. We have a couple of Entity Data Model created using EF 4.0. In them, mostly we call to store procedures and the Import functions retrieves complex types.

We've migrated to Visual Studio 2012 (but we didn't migrated to .Net 4.5). 
We wanted to start using a new version of EF. We are trying to use EF 4.3.

We did not migrate the old models generated by EF 4.0. But we've tried to create new models using EF 4.3 in the same assembly. We were able to created, but when we run it, it failed with the following exception:

**The type parameter '{Namespace.ComplexTypeName}' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type '{Namespace.ComplexTypeName}' returned by the function.**

If we created the model using EF 4.3 in separate assembly, they works fine.

Then, I'm wondering if there are some kind of imcompatibility between those versions which causes those models couldn't exist in the same assembly. I've looked for some oficial source which confirm my guess but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!,
David.

Comment: It's impossible to move to VS2012 without moving to .NET Framework 4.5 since VS2012 depends on the .NET Framework 4.5 and will install one if it is not there. Note that .Net Framework 4.5 is an in-place update so there is no change in major and minor versions (i.e. the assembly versions are stil 4.0.30319 (4.0.30319.17929)). Even if you target .NET Framework 4 in your app it will effectively run on .NET Framework 4.5 if it was installed. With EF 4.3-are you using CodeFirst?if you say models in the same assembly-are these 2 sets of entities with the same names?are they EntityObject based?

Comment: Hi Pawel. Thanks for your quick feedback. Regarding VS 2012 and .Net 4.5, yes we were aware about what are you mention. We are targering to 4.0 because our site need to be deployed in MS Server 2003 which is not compatible with .Net 4.5.

Comment: And regarding EF 4.3. No, we are not using Code First. It is database first. And we do not have 2 sets of entities with the same name. In fact, there are not entities, they are complex types. We are just calling to one store procedure, then we have a Import function which retrieve a list of complex types. And the complex types were generated automatically by EF.

Comment: From what you are saying is that you don't need EF4.3 or anything like that. EF4.3 does not know how to work with edmx files and it seems to me that you are actually not using it at all. You said you "tried to create new model in the same assembly" [as old models]. This indicates that you have old and new models in the same assembly which I meant by having to sets of types. You probably use new the new model when the old one is expected.